# Writing your own version of windows

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

Recently, I've been thinking about how there are multiple versions of linux and how they are all built on a similar kernel. And I was wondering if it was possible with Windows. In this case I am thinking of having the first program loaded after the kernel has booted up and started all the devices, would be the what pops up instead of the windows login screen.

The reason for this is because I was wondering if it was possible to have the system render all the objects on the screen in a distint styling, but still process it as if it were running on a normal windows machine.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: The windows Kernel controls pretty much everything except the GUI.  However, it sounds like the GUI is the part you want to replace. Window's GUI is explorer.exe, which is replacable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell_replacement

Comment: @MooingDuck: Windows architecture is a bit more complicated than that. But yes, you can replace the shell (it's not the GUI/WM component, though).

Comment: Where would the source come from? I believe the "kernal" of Windows is fiercely protected company proprietary info, no?

Comment: cool, does that also process the rendering of all the objects? if so, is there anywhere where there would be a list of the commands it would be ready to receive and calls it should make?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Yeah, I had only the vaguest idea of what I was talking about.  But I had a link!

Comment: @Sinthia V why would you need the source, if the commands are accessible by preceding program, and via versa, you can see them too. The by processing what is seen by capture tests, you could work it out. But that would take time, and not quite sure I know how... I was just hoping for a slightly easier root.

Comment: @Chris You can't do this. Not a hope.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I bored and game, sounds like a bit of fun

Comment: @SinthiaV: "kernel" is the correct spelling.

Comment: Replacing the login screen is not replacing the shell. The latter is fairly straightforward. The former requires you to reimplement large chunks of Winlogon, a critical system process. This is not recommended.

Comment: Thats what i thought, but wouldnt be to bad go through the challenge response exchange with a memory logger on. Would be fairly experimental, but it could be a useful piece of funsy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I thought this was a naive question, but Mooing Duck's link in the comments proved insightful. There are projects that do just this: [EmergeDesktop](http://www.emergedesktop.org/), [SharpE](http://www.sharpenviro.com/wp/), even the KDE.

They're open and on sourceforge, go get them and dink around to your hearts content.

I'm not sure that the login screen is part of the shell however. So your alternate shell would only show up after you log in.

However, in the long run, alternate shells have no hope of competition. Microsoft controls the environment and they don't play too nice with competition.

Comment: Could just be fun, but it was naive, thats why i asked. Linux is probably the nicest option, just wondering if it was possible and to execute windows binaries in your own environment of sorts